# How to remove records with character(0) in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyr

I would like to remove the rows in a data frame with character(0). For example

```
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c(character(0), c(2012,2034), c(2012,2013)
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

I would like to have rows

```
A      B
2     c(2012,2034)
3     c(2012,2013)
```

Comment: Not correct code. Mismatching parentheses. Using `c` will eliminate the character(0) items. Please post code that will be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like :

```
A<- list(1,2,3)
B<- list(character(0), c(2012,2034), c(2012,2013))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(A=A[lengths(B)>0],B=B[lengths(B)>0]))
```

Comment: Or `data.frame(I(A),I(B))[lengths(B)>0,]` - though I am guessing OP is in a total tangle and their example may or may not resemble what they actually have.